# OnTouch ImageView frame animation set default image

Tags: android, frame, drawable, ontouchlistener

I've been trying to look for a solution, but it seems like no one tried it, or maybe its too simple that I did not find it.

Anyways, I'm trying to achieve a button press with an `ImageView`. What I want is, `ImageView` to display a default image, and if pressed (OnTouch) [which has a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` block] to run a frame animation. When you release the touch [which has a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` block], it should stop the animation and return to the default image.

Note: Frame animation is continuous repeating, and should not include the default image as one of the looped through image. (Button up image should not be displayed when touching)

Now the problem is, I have the animation working, but as per the android documentation, the first item in the `<animation-list>` tag will be displayed by default. But if I add the default image (button un-touched state) as the first item, it will be displayed in the loop. Also, when I release the touch, I use `stop()` method of the `AnimationDrawable`, which stops the animation at the current frame (image) and I can't seem to find any way to stop and go to default image state.

Here is my code:

button_anim.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_press1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_press2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_press3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_anim);
    buttonAnim = (AnimationDrawable)button.getBackground();
    button.setOnTouchListener(buttonTest);
}
private OnTouchListener buttonTest = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            buttonAnim.start();
            // Log.d("Test", "Touch down");
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            buttonAnim.stop();
            // Log.d("Test", "Touch Stop");
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Default image:- `button1_inactive.png`

Answer (score 0):

```
        buttonAnim.stop();
        buttonAnim.reset();
        // Log.d("Test", "Touch Stop");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AnimationDrawable mFrameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)button.getBackground();
mFrameAnimation.stop(); 
mFrameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow, try to explain more, and describe the details, don't put a bunch of source code as a answer, thanks ;)